# Android Parse.com query user by pointer

Tags: android, pointers, parse-platform

I have a problem querying the data of a user using pointer, so this is my tables (class):

_User

```
objectId<string> |   username<string> | ...
```

Posts

```
objectId<string>   |   post<string>  |   writerId <pointer>(_User)
```

The writerId contains the user id of the writer of the post.

I'm showing the posts in a custom ListView in this way:

```
 variables_posts = new ArrayList<VariablesPosts>();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Posts");
    query.selectKeys(Arrays.asList("post"));
    query.include("writerId");
    on = query.find();
    for (ParseObject post : on) {
          VariablesPosts map = new VariablesPosts();
           map.setWriter((String) post.get("username"));
           map.setPost((String) post.get("post"));
           variables_posts.add(map);}
```

The problem is that the writerId is a pointer and not a string if I put

```
map.setWriter((String) post.get("writerId"));
```

The app will crash, so I used from another help the line `query.include("writerId");` to directly get the username but this line:

```
map.setwriter((String) post.get("username"));
```

is crashing the app too, when I delete it the app works fine, so in my case how can I get the username from User class by the pointer writerId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exact Java syntax, but when you include writerId and then want to get username of that writerId User, you must first get the User object from Post's writerId .. something like:
 `(String)((ParseUser)post.get("writerId")).get("username")`

Comment: Thanks this worked. The problème was with line query.selectKeys(); once deleted you line works good

Answer (score 0):

Your naming of the pointer column is a little misleading as the column does not contain IDs. You should call it *writer* instead.

To get the username, do this:

```
query.include("writerId");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> postList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (ParseObject post : postList) {                
                ParseObject writer = post.getParseObject("writerId");
                String userName = writer.getString("username");
                // .. (do whatever with userName)
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("post", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```